# PHP or Perl for serial communication with micro controller

Tags: php, html, perl, serial-port, microcontroller

I'm doing something new with my micro controller, but I only have a little experience on the computer side.
Suppose I want my controller to send certain data through serial port to my PC, the PC upon receiving, then processes the data and updates certian fields on a web page. At the same web page I can send data to my controller. So this is a 2 way communication.
I know that the later can be achieved with PHP fopen then fwrite to the TTY device, but how do I process the data once my PC received them from the controller? Do I have to have a Perl script running on the back or PHP can take care of it all?

Thanks!

Comment: PHP can do it. Give some hint about "processes the data and updates certian fields on a web page"

Comment: Basically just displays data coming from the controller. What I'm confuse about is that can PHP automatically process it (like interrupts in a controller) or PHP has to request the data from the controller first, then process it

Comment: Both can be possible.ok how you are planning to send data to php or vice versa

Comment: check this link. It may help you... http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think that is the problem I'm having, I know there's a PHP-Serial module on the web, but why do I need that if I can use fopen /dev/TTY? Or are there other way to send data to PHP?

Comment: Ok how you are going to use fopen /dev/TTY to send data to php.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options: [IO::Termios](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aTermios), [Device::SerialPort](http://p3rl.org/Device%3a%3aSerialPort), [AnyEvent::SerialPort](http://p3rl.org/AnyEvent%3a%3aSerialPort), [Device::SerialPort::Arduino](http://p3rl.org/Device%3a%3aSerialPort%3a%3aArduino)… You didn't give any info about your controller, so check CPAN whether it is supported directly.

`IO::Termios` synopsis:

```
use IO::Termios qw();

my $term = IO::Termios->open('/dev/ttyS0')
    or die "Cannot open ttyS0 - $!";

$term->setbaud(9600);
$term->setcsize(8);
$term->setparity('n');
$term->setstop(1);

$term->print("Hello world\n");  # send to the device

while (<$term>) {   # loop continuously and read from device
    print "A line from ttyS0: $_";
}
```